# Linux; Change UID to root if you are not root

Tags: c, linux, root, uid

I write a simple program

When you run this program, if you are not `root` user, input `root` password, then change uid to root

```
if (getuid())
{
    char *pass = getpass("");
    //how to change uid to root ?
}
```

How to change uid to root when you got `root` password?

Comment: Just to mention: don't store the root password unencrypted in your program, use a hashing function.

Comment: `if (getuid)` is a lot different from `if (getuid())`. The former is always-true...

Comment: @TNW: That's not really helpful if you can't authenticate without the unhashed version.

Comment: I had change `if (getuid)` to `if (getuid())`

Comment: Can you simply use sudo when invoking your program? If not, perhaps you should lookup the source code of sudo for whichever platform you are implementing on and use it as a guide to implement your privilege escalation.

Comment: Don't do that (because you probably will open a huge security hole in your system). Use and configure existing tools (`sudo`, `su`, `super`). FYI, you could configure `sudo` to not ask any password if you really want to (but that is risky).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to change from a non-root user to root. That's the whole point. Programs like `login`, `sshd`, or `su` work by initially *starting as root*, either because of their ancestry or by having the suid bit on the executable file, and carefully restricting what you can do until you authenticate with a password or other method, then changing to an appropriate uid (either root or the user you're logging in as) and `exec`'ing another program (usually, the shell).

Comment: A program able to be root is indeed *setuid* root (e.G. to start as root), but more importantly it has to be very carefully designed to avoid opening huge security holes in your system. So don't do it, unless you spend a lot of time to understand all the tricks and implications.... Read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/